# Как получить массив из json в c#

Tags: c#, json

Есть страница php которая получает данные из базы и преобразует в json. Получаю через Web запрос строку с json и десериализую через библиотеку Newtonsoft.Json. С одной записью справляется без проблем, но с двумя уже вылетает исключение. В List засунуть не получается.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://h92761ae.beget.tech/json.php");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            result = result.Remove(0,1);
            result = result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);

            RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);

            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.id);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.id_template);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.discription);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");
            Console.WriteLine(rootObject.device_code);
            Console.WriteLine("------------");

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string id_template { get; set; }
        public string discription { get; set; }
        public string device_code { get; set; }
    }
```

Приходящий json:

```
[{"id":"1","id_template":"1","discription":"qweerty","device_code":"dvc-001"},{"id":"4","id_template":"2","discription":"dwagrhnthteh","device_code":"dvc-002"}]
```

Comment: Пример приходящего json'а добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: А это `result = result.Remove(0,1);` зачем?

Comment: Смотреть `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Bulson Чтобы удалить квадратные скобки в начале и в конце. Без этих команд так же вылетает исключение

Comment: Если `result.Remove(0,1)` удалит одну скобку то вторая...?

Comment: Удаляя скобки, вы уродуете json, квадратные скобки обозначают массив.

Comment: @Bulson, даже не удаляя скобок. У него проблема, что он json бьет на куски и пытается парсить как цельный json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во первых, вы много делаете лишнего для получения данных! Для их получения можно обойтись 1-2 строками кода, ведь у вас нет на сервере проверок того, какой запрос должен быть, какие данные получить хотите и тд.

Перепишем все получение в две строки:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var str = client.DownloadString("HTTP...");
```

После выполнения данного кода у вас в переменной `str` будет весь ваш `JSON`.

Ок, давайте теперь поговорим про проблему. Вы получаете массив, который пытаете запарсить как одиночный объект. К тому же вы массив походу и вовсе хотите на стороне клиента убрать, путем удаления первого символа (`result = result.Remove(0,1);`), это не правильно!

Для грамотного получения ваших данных достаточно опять же указать всего 1 строку:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(str);
```

Заметьте, мы задаем `RootObject`, как массив, а не единичный объект. На выходе переменная `json` будет содержать массив всех объектов с сервера, по которому достаточно пройтись циклом и вывести все, что вам нужно.

Пример:

```
foreach (var rootObject in json)
{
    Console.WriteLine(rootObject.id);
    Console.WriteLine("------------");
    Console.WriteLine(rootObject.id_template);
    Console.WriteLine("------------");
    Console.WriteLine(rootObject.discription);
    Console.WriteLine("------------");
    Console.WriteLine(rootObject.device_code);
    Console.WriteLine("------------");
}
```

Comment: У него была проблема, что он json бьет на куски и пытается парсить как цельный json.

Comment: @hitcode Вы немного не правы, автор вопроса удаляет обозначение массива в полученном `JSON` и пытается десериализовать, как единичный объект, что в корне не верно. Сказать, что он разбивает `JSON` - у меня лично язык не повернется, так, как "разбить" в моем понимание, это из одной строки получить две (split скажем), в предоставленном коде мы видим лишь удаление первого и последнего символа, это не "разбитие".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Благодарю за ответ! Как будет возможность попробую реализовать ваш способ

Answer (score 2):

Держи. Немного изменил твой код.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace JsonTest
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string id_template { get; set; }
        public string discription { get; set; }
        public string device_code { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://h92761ae.beget.tech/json.php");

            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream receiveStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

            List<RootObject> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(readStream.ReadToEnd());
            foreach (RootObject element in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("------------");
                Console.WriteLine(element.id);
                Console.WriteLine("------------");
                Console.WriteLine(element.id_template);
                Console.WriteLine("------------");
                Console.WriteLine(element.discription);
                Console.WriteLine("------------");
                Console.WriteLine(element.device_code);
                Console.WriteLine("------------");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: тестирование app]

Comment: Спасибо. Пытался делать через List, но не получалось, понял где накосячил